# Client side program will get the list of USB Devices connected to different PC's on LAN and send it to the server which will display it

Tags: c#, server, usb, client

Will Develop the Application using C#. The program at client side will run continuously in the background and will send the list of USB Devices to server every few seconds(or when new device is connected or disconnected). Server side program will receive the info from different clients and will display it.

---

The Problems i am facing are:

---

1) How to keep the client side program running in background and make it to send the list of devices(string) to the server periodically?

---

2) How to make the server side program receive info from many clients at a time?

---

Any Suggestions are welcome. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Note that you could also get the server to query the client using WMI or similar, avoiding the need to write a client application at all. This will only work if they are in the same intranet, and permissions permitting though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows Service. `Windows Service` can be installed and will run continuously in background. To send data periodically, you can use `Timer` if time interval is fixed else you can use `FileSystemWatcher` where your data comes and it will trigger a function.